# Drawing a game board in C

Tags: c, coordinates, 2d-games, coordinate-systems

Well, as the title says, I'm trying to draw a game board. Well the board itself I did and it looks something like his:

```
4 |
3 |
2 |
1 |
0 |
   - - - - -
   0 1 2 3 4
```

but that's not the problem. The thing I find hard is the I wanna draw icons of star shape (*) on the board, and the coordinates are giving in an array like this

```
posX {2,4,2,1}
posY {2,3,4,4}
```

so in this case I should draw * in the coordinates (2,2) , (4,3) , (2,4) , (1,4) and so on. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't "go back" in the output stream using the standard C features. You will need some dedicated libraries like `ncurses`. Or redraw the whole board every time.

Comment: well I'm sure there is a way, its part of an assignment I have :( @EugeneSh.

Comment: Then probably the second approach was meant.

Comment: What console do you use? if it is VT100 compatible, [escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) are useful.

Comment: Or maybe you are building a GUI software?

Comment: If it's a console program you should redraw the whole board each time. That's probably what is required by your homework.

Comment: yeah I think so, anyway could you please help me and tell me how? even if I have to redraw it each time thanks @MikeCAT

Comment: If you are using MSVC you could use [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where there is example code.

Comment: @thaeer show your code that draws the board, then wen can tell you more.

Comment: I'm using codeBlocks and I cant use any function I didn't create, the only two libraries I can use are stdio.h and stdlib.h :( @WeatherVane

Comment: Redrawing the board means that you'll print this board without forgetting the stars, what's unclear about it?

Comment: @MichaelWalz the function I created to draw the starting point cant help cause it draws an empty board and I cant add anything to it (like adding an array of numbers) I should create a new one, do you still want to see it ?

Comment: Tip: prepare an array of strings filled with `space` characters and `\0`-terminated, then "poke" the text characters you need, into the arrays. Finally, print all the prepared lines in a loop.

Comment: yeah I think I'm getting somewhere thanks man @WeatherVane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This illustrates what I meant in my comment, perhaps it helps. It prepares an array of strings representing the game board, before printing them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BOARDX  5
#define BOARDY  5
#define BOARDW  (BOARDX*2)              // length of text line

char board [BOARDY][BOARDW+1];          // allow for string terminator

void print_board(void)
{
    int y, x;
    for(y=BOARDY-1; y>=0; y--) {
        printf("%-2d|%s\n", y, board[y]);
    }

    printf("   ");
    for(x=0; x<BOARDX; x++)
        printf(" -");
    printf("\n");

    printf("   ");
    for(x=0; x<BOARDX; x++)
        printf("%2d", x);
    printf("\n");
}

void empty_board(void)
{
    int y, x;
    for(y=0; y<BOARDY; y++) {
        for(x=0; x<BOARDW; x++) {
            board[y][x] = ' ';
        }
        board[y][x] = '\0';
    }
}

void poke_board(int x, int y, char c)
{
    if (y >= 0 && y < BOARDY && x >= 0 && x < BOARDX)
       board[y][x*2+1] = c;               // correctly spaced
}

int main(void)
{
    int posX[]= {2,4,2,1};
    int posY[]= {2,3,4,4};
    int len = sizeof(posX) / sizeof(posX[0]);
    int n;
    empty_board();
    for(n=0; n<len; n++) {
        poke_board(posX[n], posY[n], '*');
    }
    print_board();
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
4 |   * *
3 |         *
2 |     *
1 |
0 |
    - - - - -
    0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: yeah that perfect, but I get the array from another function so what changes should I do to make this function do the same for an array the user gives me?
@Weather Vane

Comment: Thanks for the vote, but I can't guess what code you have or which of the three arrays in this code you are talking about. Perhaps time to ask another question?

Answer (score 5):

If you are printing these on the termial (console), You can not simply print the coordinate axis and the go back and put coordinates, however if your coordinate system is sufficiently small, you should not have a problem with redrawing the entire board every time a new point is added.

One simple approach is to keep a 2d array of char and either put " " or "*" based on the coordinates. This way you can simply print the 2D array row by row every time a new point is added to the coordinates.

Of course you are also responsible for printing the axes but that part should be straight forward.

```
char points [4][4] ={
       {' ',' ',' ',' '},
       {' ',' ',' ',' '},
       {' ',' ',' ',' '},
       {' ',' ',' ',' '},
       };
```

Is what you will have as an empty board. now if you want to enter something at coordinates (1,2), all you need to do is to say `points[1][2]='*';`

to print the entire array you will need a nested loop, the outer to traverse the rows and the inner to traverse the columns. something like this:

```
int i,j;

for (i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for (j=0; j<4; ++j) printf("%c ", points[i][j]);

     printf("\n");
     }
```

This way the coordinate values will be increasing from left to right and from top to bottom. if you want otherwise you should change the for loop bounds.

to refresh the screen I recommend you print a whole bunch of newlines to effectively clear the screen. there are other ways of doing this (like system("cls"), but not as pain free